# How to copy list content to anther list most efficient

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have 2 big lists that contain heavy objects and I need to join them into a single list. My first instinct was to create a new list and append the content of those 2 into it as follow:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.addAll(list1);
items.addAll(list2);
```

However, as this is an ArrayList in order to copy those 2 big lists I need to allocate new memory instead of using the existing once and copy the references.

My thought now was to use LinkedList and copy the end node of `list1` into the head of `list2` however as much as I can say from the documentation there is no such method.

Is there a better way to concatenate 2 lists without re-allocation of new memory? and if not, what is the best practice in such a case?

Comment: It only creates a new List with references to the old heavy objects. It does not allocate memory for copies of the objects. Apart from minimal optimizations with the intitial capacity as per @stephen-c s answer, this is the optimal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most memory / GC efficient way to do it:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(list1.size() + list2.size());
items.addAll(list1);
items.addAll(list2);
```

The trick is to provide an accurate `capacity` when creating the list; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-).  This saves any double copying to "grow" the target list (i.e. `list`).

> My thought now was to use `LinkedList` and copy the end node of `list1` into the head of `list2` however as much as I can say from the documentation there is no such method.

`LinkedList` use more memory per list entry than `ArrayList`.  By a factor of 4 or more.

Besides, when you use `addAll` from one `LinkedList` to another, you are creating new list node objects.

---

> I have 2 big lists that contain heavy objects ....

The *weight* (size) of the objects is not relevant.  A `List` contains references to the objects, not copies of the objects themselves.

---

> Is there a better way to concatenate 2 lists without re-allocation of new memory?

There is no way to concatenate two `java.util.List` instances without allocating more memory.  The best you can do is minimize the allocation.

On the other hand ... if you were prepared to implement your own linked list data structure, you *could* join two lists together by "splicing" them.  But you the `List` API doesn't allow that kind of thing.  (For a start, it mutilates the original lists.)

---

It is true that premature optimization is a bad thing.  However, if you already have strong evidence that the lists involved *will* be large, then this is arguably not premature.

Answer (score 0):

> My thought now was to use LinkedList and copy the end node of list1
>   into the head of list2 however as much as I can say from the
>   documentation there is no such method.

You can do the same using Array list as follows:

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```

And after adding list2, You can ask GC to reclaim the memory used by list2 as follows:

```
list2 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The lists hold references to objects, not actual objects themselves. Unless you want to create a new list which has to have a deep copy of all the objects.

1. If you don't mind modifying one of the lists, add all contents to one of the lists and reclaim memory from other list.

```
list1.addAll(list2);
list2.clear();

// You could also reclaim memory using garbage collector.

list1.addAll(list2);
list2 = null;
System.gc();     // It's not guaranteed that Garbage collector will be invoked.
```

2. If you want to create a new list, assign capacity while doing so and reclaim memory from other lists using the steps mentioned in step (1).

However, it mainly depends on you use case. Remember:-

> Microoptimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Why would you run a full gc only to reclaim a single list object?

Comment: Yea.  Running `System.gc()` is a bad idea (inefficient) AND it is not guaranteed to reclaim the memory anyway.

Comment: It's just for OP's reference. Of course, I've mentioned in the code comments that it's not guaranteed to run. Besides, in terms of efficiency, the GC daemon runs on a separate thread. This is to ensure that the main thread isn't starved due to GC operations. 


Quoting the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()), "Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse"